# Explicit table cell height not respected

Tags: xsl-fo, antenna-house

I am trying to determine why the following XSLFO code does not make the table cell and as a consequence, the contained image, 25% of the page height:

```
<fo:table table-layout="auto" border-collapse="collapse" keep-together.within-page="always">
  <fo:table-body>
    <fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-cell block-progression-dimension.maximum="25pvh">
        <fo:block>
          <fo:external-graphic 
scaling="uniform" 
src="images/tall.png" 
content-height="scale-down-to-fit" 
inline-progression-dimension.maximum="auto" 
inline-progression-dimension.optimum="auto" 
inline-progression-dimension.minimum="auto" 
block-progression-dimension.minimum="auto" 
block-progression-dimension.optimum="auto" 
block-progression-dimension.maximum="100%" />
        </fo:block>
      </fo:table-cell>
    </fo:table-row>
  </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

The output is:

[image: Image too high, should be 25%]

I'd expect the table cell, and as a consequence, the embedded tall image (which is higher than the page height at its intrinsic size), to be at max 25% of the page height, due to setting `<fo:table-cell block-progression-dimension.maximum="25pvh">`.

Why is the table with its single cell still 100% of the available content height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
    <fo:table-row block-progression-dimension.maximum="25pvh">
      <fo:table-cell block-progression-dimension.maximum="25pvh">
```

---

Was:

Either move the `block-progression-dimension.maximum="25pvh"` to the `fo:table-row` or use `height` on the `fo:table-cell`.

I am checking to see whether it is an Antenna House Formatter bug, but the current result might be because a row with `auto` row height uses the actual height of the content of its table cells.

---

https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#height refers to http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/tables.html for the height of table rows.

https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#height-layout includes:

> The height of a 'table-row' element's box is calculated once the user agent has all the cells in the row available: it is the maximum of the row's computed 'height', the computed 'height' of each cell in the row, and the minimum height (MIN) required by the cells. A 'height' value of 'auto' for a 'table-row' means the row height used for layout is MIN. MIN depends on cell box heights and cell box alignment (much like the calculation of a line box height).

and:

> In CSS 2.1, the height of a cell box is the minimum height required by the content. The table cell's 'height' property can influence the height of the row (see above), but it does not increase the height of the cell box.

From https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_table-cell:

> The method for determining the block-progression-dimension of the cell in the grid is governed by the row-height trait.

The `fo:table-row` definition has a similar statement, but the 'row-height' trait isn't actually defined in XSL 1.1.

You haven't restricted the height of the content of the `fo:table-cell`, so the row is taking the height of the cell's content.

From https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_external-graphic:

> The viewport's size is determined by the block-progression-dimension and inline-progression-dimension traits. For values of "auto", the content size of the graphic is used.

Comment: Thanks Tony, this is really helpful! You replied: _You haven't restricted the height of the content of the fo:table-cell_ . So you are saying there is no way to just **limit** the height of a `table-cell` itself (e.g. if its – variable – contents is less in height than that maximum, I'd want it to only use that little vertical space), but only for the containing row? With reason being that the cell's `block-progression-dimension.optimum` is `auto`, and `.maximum` having no actual effect on calculating "100% of auto" for establishing the cell's content?

Comment: It gets a bit murky and subject to interpretation (IMO). From https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#block-progression-dimension: "The percentage is calculated with respect to the corresponding dimension of the closest area ancestor that was generated by a block-level formatting object. If that dimension is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content's block-progression-dimension), the value is interpreted as 'auto'." With 'auto' `height` on the `fo:table-row`, the row height depends on the cell box height. When the cell height depends on itself, that '100%' is treated as 'auto', which ...

Comment: ... becomes the content height of the graphic. The part that I'm still checking is whether the `<fo:table-cell block-progression-dimension.maximum="25pvh">` alone should restrict the formatted height of the graphic or whether, as in my edit, you also need to specify it on the `fo:table-row` to forestall the 'auto' behaviour.

Comment: The next maintenance release of Antenna House Formatter will resize the graphic with just `<fo:table-cell block-progression-dimension.maximum="25pvh">`.